# how to configure to allow a lib can be used both in src and test?

Tags: maven-2, maven

i want my lib can be used by both in src and test class.
there is a scope properties... should i do something with it?

thanks?

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <scope>what should i put here</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you take "compile" or you remove the scope tag, as "compile" is the default for it anyway.